# How to transfer the content of an AppleScript variable to an Objective-C action

Tags: applescript, xcode5

I am trying to understand actions created with XCode 5 for OSX Automator.

So I used the template "Automator Action" like this :

```
- ( id )runWithInput:( id )input fromAction:( AMAction * )anAction error:( NSDictionary ** )errorInfo
{
    // we expect to receive "Hello World" in the input variable

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *desktopDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get desktop directory
    NSString *logStr = @"";

    logStr = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"founded %lu", (unsigned long)[input count]];
    [ logStr writeToFile:[ desktopDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt" ] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];

    return input;        
}
```

In Automator, I have created 2 steps :

First : an AppleScript action that does this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return "Hello World"
end run
```

As you can see It just returns the text "Hello World"

Second, my action that I created with Xcode.

But when I run the workflow ... there's no errors but input parameter (that is an NSArray) contains nothing!

Do you know how to transfer the content of an AppleScript variable  to an Objective-C action?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found!

In the project settings under "Input type accepted by the Automator Action" I replaced com.apple.cocoa.path by com.apple.cocoa.string

and there I get good value.